# Pandas assign series to a column based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

DF1:

```
          Count

0         98.0
1        176.0
2        260.5
3        389.0
```

I have to assign these values to a column in another dataframe for every 3rd row starting from 3rd row.

The Output of DF2 should look like this:

```
         Count

0         
1
2        98.0
3        
4        
5        176.0
6 
7
8        260.5
9
10
11       389.0
```

I am doing

```
DF2.loc[2::3,'Count'] = DF1['Count']
```

But, I am not getting the expected results.

Comment: what are you getting? including outputs is always recommended

Comment: I am getting Nan for all rows.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `values`

Ohterwise, Pandas tries to align the index values from `DF1` and that messes you up.

```
DF2.loc[2::3, 'Count'] = DF1['Count'].values
DF2

    Count
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    98.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5   176.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8   260.5
9     NaN
10    NaN
11  389.0
```

---

#### New From `DF1`

```
DF1.set_index(DF1.index * 3 + 2).reindex(range(len(DF1) * 3))

    Count
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    98.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5   176.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8   260.5
9     NaN
10    NaN
11  389.0
```